# Does the following function have a maximum at $(1,1)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> Given the function $$f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 − 1)^2 + (x_2 − 1)^3$$ is $(1,1)$ a maximizer / minimizer of $f$?

The necessary conditions are fulfilled: the gradient is zero and the Hessian is PSD at $(1,1)$.

The professor teaching the course suggests me to consider the restriction to the line: $x=(1,1+2t)$.
The restricted function is $f_v(t)=8t^3$. Then my professor writes that $f_v(t)$ is always increasing and then it does not have a a min/ max at $t=0$ (??)? I do not understand why this implies that $(1,1)$ is not a max nor a min.

Comment: Do you know the definition of local extremum?

Comment: Does $f(x)=x^3$ have a min/max at $x=0$?

Comment: Why do we care about what happens at 0, if the candidate point is $(1,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from your professor's suggestion that $f(1,1+2t)<f(1,1)$ if $t<0$ and that $f(1,1+2t)>f(1,1)$ if $t>0$. Therefore, $(1,1)$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum of $f$.

Comment: So if I considered instead the restriction to (1,2t), I should have checked whether $f_v(t)$ had a minimum at $t=1/2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.